# html2canvas, upload image to wordpress library

Tags: wordpress, upload, html2canvas

I'm making a holiday blessing generator for client.
The final output goes to a div with an id="BRHBresults".
From that div I'm making a canvas and converting it to image, 
I've managed to make the onclick function to download the image(just to make sure the result was correct), however what I need the onclick to do is,
upload the image to wordpress library and make a new post with this image as post_thumbnail.
I get an error: 
"414 (Request-URI Too Large)"
So far I have come up with this:

Link to the page: [http://www.benedict.co.il/%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9C-%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA/
]
Javascript/JQuery

```js
$(".BRHshareToFB1").click(function(){
            html2canvas([document.getElementById('BRHBresults')], {
                onrendered: function (canvas) {
                    var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                    var image = new Image();
                    image.src = data;
                    var alink = data ;
                    //$('.BRHshareToFB2').attr('href', alink);
                    //$('.BRHshareToFB2').attr('download', 'filename.jpg');
                    //dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                    alink = data.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
                    $.post("/send.php?data="+alink);
                }
            });
        });
```

PHP from send.php file

```html
<?php
$dir = getcwd();
$now = date("U");
$imgstring = $_POST['data'];
$imgstring = base64_decode($imgstring);
file_put_contents("$dir/wp-content/uploads/blessing-$now.png", $imgstring);
?>
```

What am I missing? Please help! :)